# Socket.io-Client: React+TypeScript: Socket.io-client not listening from the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I have a server code which looks as follows:

```
import express, { Response } from "express";
import { Server, Socket } from "socket.io";
import { createServer, Server as S } from "http";
// import router from "./routes";

// ----
const app: express.Application = express();
// app.use(router);

app.get("/", (_req: any, res: Response) =>
  res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
);
const PORT: any = 3001 || process.env.PORT;
const server: S = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {});

io.on("connection", (socket: Socket) => {
  console.log("we have a new connection");
  console.log(socket.id);
});
//
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`The server is running on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

In my `index.html`  this is my code:

```html
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
    </script>
```

When i visited the web at http://localhost:3001 i get console logs, socket.io listening on new connections. What i want is to use the `socket.io-client` with a react server running on port 3000. Here is what i've tried:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
const client = io("http://localhost:3001/").connect();
const App: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>Socket.io</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When i visited http://localhost:3000 nothing is being logged on the screen, what maybe possibly the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After some looking on my react-app i realized that the problem was with `cors`. So I set `cors` on the server and everything worked:

```
const server: S = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});
....
```